# Email to case is not creating case

Tags: email2case

[image]I have set email to case, Verified email address. Although when I forward test email directly to the salesforce generated email address(for email to case) it is not creating case within my organisation. I understand that email to case should ignore validation rules and required fields.

I have also troubleshoot using information in this [Knowledge Article](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000003944&type=1) but no luck. 
Is there anything I am missing?

Comment: Hard to tell without any screenshot, do you mind sharing your email to case settings?

Comment: Ya sure. I have added screeshot of my settings.

Comment: Check in the setup, if your [email deliverability](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=emailadmin_deliverability.htm&type=0) is **all** or **system** emails.

Comment: it is for All emails.

Comment: Can you please show the Email-to-Case Settings?

Comment: Ya I already added screenshot.

Comment: if you have a trigger check that, if any error is occurring. Also, if you have set up Automated User correctly then that user will receive email. Make sure email id correct.